# Post request not working on Restful API Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, rest, jsonresponse

I have installed RESTful Codeigniter API on my Codeigniter project. When I test API Example and call through Chrome postman rest client by http://textilexports.com/donate/api/example/users url, I got that error in Post response.

```
{
    "id": 100
    "name": null
    "email": null
    "message": "Added a resource"
}
```

---

```
public function users_post()
{
    // $this->some_model->update_user( ... );
    $message = [
        'id' => 100, // Automatically generated by the model
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'message' => 'Added a resource'
    ];
    $this->set_response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your REST API using RESTED client in Firefox.Below is the output when you passed parameters as mentioned in screen shot.Do the same in chrome extension.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for help. can you tell me why its not working on  Chrome (Advance Rest Client). Thanks                   http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=14_1786.png,                                                                                                                                                           http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=14_2343.png

Comment: You can see in that images

Comment: Issue is you are trying to send POST parameters via header information.Its wrong.So you have to use Data form to send POST parameters.Then everything ok.i've tested it via Advanced Rest Client too.its working properly.

Comment: How to get get responce data in xml format for post call

Comment: Hello Dhanu,you can add format parameter as like this http://example.com/books?format=xml
also u can use json & serialized PHP out put too